# Email has different styling than VF email template preview

Tags: visualforce-component, email-template

I am no sure if anyone has this issue or this is related to gmail.

Visualforce email template preview styling is want I am looking for. However , the recieved email is plain and not table border in it. I tried the salesforce developer guide example too. Both has same problem.

can anyone help to fix this issue.

Preview:
[image: Preview]

Actual Email : with different styling
[image: ActualEmail via test send]

Comment: Can you provide the email template for troubleshooting?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue -[docs here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000324370&type=1&mode=1). It mainly depends on the email client interpreter engine. My experience with that was unpleasant - there was a huge problem with email rendering on Outlook. You can try to use inline css but I can't guarantee that it will work on all clients

Comment: ho no..... thank you..